# MongooseJS -- $pullAll from embedded document by value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Currently I have the following scheme model:

```
var userModel = mongoose.schema({
    images: {
        public: [{url: {type: String}}]}
});
```

I want to remove items from "images.public" from their url value, rather than their ID.

```
var to_remove = [{url: "a"}, {url: "b"}];
// db entry with id "ID" contains entries with these properties.

userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(ID,
            {$pullAll: {"images.public": to_remove}},
            function(err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    throw(err);
                }
            }
        );
```

However, this does not show any errors and do not remove the items I want to remove from the database. How would I appropriately target this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Notice the change of structure in to_remove
var to_remove = ["a", "b"];
userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(ID,
    {$pull: {"images.public": {url: {$in: to_remove}}}},
        function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                throw(err);
            }
        }
    );
```

Issue here being that the structure of variable `to_remove` changed, luckily that was not a problem in my case.